# Why am I getting repeated responses from API call?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am sending an API request and get back duplicated or repeated responses from the data. I send API requests for dog name and id for each dog and put the data in html location. First dog comes three times then comes the second dog then the first dog again then the third dog then the second dog again and so on and so on.

I've tried the fetch API and async await and they both do the same thing. I've also used map, forEach and for in with all the same results.

```
fetch(api)
.then(response =>{
   return response.json();
})
.then(data => {
  console.log(data)
  let dogs = data;
  let output = '';
  dogs.forEach(dog => {
      console.log(dog.id);
      output+=`
      <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-md-6 col-lg-4 my-3">
      <div className="card">
        <img src="gdogs.jpg" className="img-card-top" style="height:14rem"alt="dogs"/>
          <div className="card-body text-capitalize">
            <h6 class="name-title">${dog.name}</h6>
            <h6 class="id">${dog.id}</h6>
            <h6 className="text-warning text-slanted">Provided by Dog API</h6>
          </div>
          <div className="card-footer">
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary text-capitalize" ></button>
            <a href="https://api.thedogapi.com" className="btn btn-success mx-2 text-capitalize" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">dog api</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    
    </div>
      
      `
      document.getElementById('dog-info').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', output)
  });
```

I just want the dogs to output in chronological order without repeating. I do not get any error messages. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What calls this code? is it wrapped in a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove this from the forEach loop:

`document.getElementById('dog-info').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', output)`

It should be outside it. On the same level as `output`. If I were you I'd also consider using a `.map` or `.reduce` to generate `output` string. It can simplify the code a bit.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly it. I was using map at first but changed it to see if I would get a different result. Thanks again Steve Perry!

Comment: Glad my response helped!

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the HTML for each dog into the `output` variable, along with every previous dog. Together with that you are running the call `insertAdjacentHTML` repeatedly, once for each dog. This means that every time you add the contents of `output` into your page, you get the whole contents, including every dog processed so far, not just the current one.

There are two obvious ways to remedy this. Either

1) Remove the `+` in the `+=` i.e. `output =`so thatoutput` gets overwritten each time instead of appended to.

Or

2) Move the call to `insertAdjacentHTML` to after the end of your foreach loop so that you only write the contents of `output` into the page once, when you've finished generating HTML for all the dogs.

Comment: Thanks for the response! You are absolutely correct and I am humbly grateful for the solution!